# Session in Cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to write a session from a variable in Cakephp?

I tried this code:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $data=$this->request->getData('myid');
        $this->Session->write('idanimalid', $data);
        $sessionid=$this->Session->read('idanimalid');
    }
```

This **myid** is from jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#animal.dropdown-item").click(function(){


    myid= $(this).attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/myurl/",
        data: {myid},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);


           }
        });
    })

});
```

The problem is that I tried to do this but nothing has happened.

Comment: Are you sure myid is being posted, please check in network console?

Comment: @PradeepSingh the problem i think is in jquery that he return me the  value in view but not in controller in controller the value is null.

Comment: So your problem is solved now?

Comment: @PradeepSingh noo

Comment: @PradeepSingh myid is posted because i made an alert and alert show me myid.

Comment: Have you loaded session components to start session like as `var $components = array('Session');` in your controller

Comment: @NitinKawane noo what do mean with that?

Comment: Which CakePHP version are you using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a#animal.dropdown-item").click(function(){
    var myid= $(this).attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/myurl/",
        data: {myid:myid},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
           }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: i am trying now

Comment: Please edit your question to have element code for this `$("a#animal.dropdown-item")`, I mean html

Comment: it doesn't matter i tried also with jquery cookies and its doesn't work

Comment: @Christian "_Doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific, and explain what _exactly_ happens (for example in the (network)console as asked before), and what _exactly_ should happen instead. Also please don't dismiss peoples questions just because you think they might be irrelevant, don't forget that no one here knows what your working environment looks like!

Comment: @ndm i will try to explain. i have an user that have 3 ore more animals. The user can choice one of them, with this id he can post something, for that i am doing SQL statement. Soo i am trying to get this id trugh jquery click and post it with ajax. The problem is that in controller this value is null and the SQL statement have this id as nul. But in view he post all because of **success: function(data) $("#show").html(data);**. The big problem is that i need this id to save it in cookie or to make it as session an to use it. Jquery and Cakephp , mybe i am using it wrong?

Comment: @ndm in normal php i can do this and its works also $_POST method and i can call the value when i want to du sql statement but not with cakephp. P.S.Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Christian, What you see in the network console when ajax runs, What are the params being sent

Comment: Link of on screenshot :)

Comment: @Christian [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336752/cakephp-select-from-where-jquery-null) is same as this. If you doesn't provide what your ajax request is posting, we cannot help in any manner

Comment: @PradeepSingh look here what i am trying to do to understand why is doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336752/cakephp-select-from-where-jquery-null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163472/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-christian).