# Cakephp select from where jquery null

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here are my Code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<a class="dropdown-item" id="animal"  value="1">Animal1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="animal"  value="2">Animal2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="animal"  value="3">Animal3</a>
</div>
```

I have an jQuery one click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#animal.dropdown-item").click(function() {
       var animalvalue = $(this).attr("value");

       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/mycontroller/",
            data: {animalvalue:animalvalue},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //$("#show").html(data);// here is the part of the problem
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Now I have my controller - here I "should" get the value:

```
$jqueryanimalvalue = $this->request->getdata('animalvalue');
```

So let's see the SQL statement:

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()
            ->select()
            ->join([
                'a' => [
                    'table' => 'animals',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' =>'a.id = Posts.animal_id'
                ],
                'u' => [
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' =>'u.id = a.user_id'
                ]
            ])
            ->where(['u.id' => '2',
                'a.id'=> $jqueryanimalvalue //here is null
            ]);

SELECT * FROM 
  posts Posts 
  INNER JOIN animals a ON a.id = Posts.animal_id 
  INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.user_id 
WHERE 
  (
    u.id = '2' 
    AND a.id = NULL //thats what i mean
  )
```

So that is my problem. After click he must to turn me the value of animal soo that i can make an select from. And only if I use :

```
$("#show").html(data);
```

it returns the name from the SQL statement. Why? I need this value of animal to use it also for intern in controller

```
INSERT INTO WHERE animalid = $jqueryanimalvalue
```

Comment: Please join the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163472/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-christian)

Comment: There is a whitespace at the end of key in the `getData()` call...

Comment: @ndm sorry that was my mistake when i wrote the code here. In my editor the code is without whitespace. The Problem is not about that.

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL Query is wrong:

Change this:

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()
->select()
->join([
    'a' => [
        'table' => 'animals',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' =>'a.id = Posts.animal_id'
    ],
    'u' => [
        'table' => 'users',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' =>'u.id = a.user_id'
    ]
])
->where(['u.id' => '2',
    'a.id'=> $jqueryanimalvalue //here is null
]);
```

To:

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()
->select()
->join([
    'a' => [
        'table' => 'animals',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => [
            'a.id = Posts.animal_id',
            'a.id IS ' . $jqueryanimalvalue  // if it is null
        ]
    ],
    'u' => [
        'table' => 'users',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => [
            'u.id = a.user_id',
            'u.id' => '2'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: error check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version and $jqeryanimalvalue   also here is null

Comment: You can also directly specify NULL.

Comment: noo this is the problem that i have null just take a look into my cod and you will understand

Comment: Can u please elaborate your problem? NULL is the problem or query is the problem? What you are expecting from the stackoverflow community?

Comment: as i said the problem is that in controller i have the value null and i can'T make iven an select from .

Comment: @KhattuDeveloper What you are showing here is an SQL injection vulnerability, value only array entries are being inserted into the query as is! Always use the `key => value` syntax, or bindings!

Comment: @ndm thats what i am doing, my problem is why i  turns null in controller? in view i can use it by giving in succes function **div=show** why i have it as null ?

Comment: @Christian My message was targeted to Khattu Developer to make him aware of the problem with the example he posted, it's not a solution for your problem.

Comment: @ndm i know i just need to know how to solve the problem i think you can find a solution

Comment: I already posted my observation in a comment to your question.